# numpy: get rid of for loop by broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I am trying to implement the Expectation Maximization Algorithm for Gaussian Mixture Model in python.

I have following line to compute the gaussian probability *p* of my data *X* given the mean *mu* and covariance *sigma* of the Gaussian distribution:

```
for i in range(len(X[0])):  
   p[i] = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(X[:,i],mu,sigma)
```

I wanted to know if I somehow could get rid of the for loop to get something like

```
p[:] = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(X[:,:]??)
```

I did some research on broadcasting and was thinking about using the `numpy.einsum` function but can't figure out how it would work in this case.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Yeah it did! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flatten, use the `pdf` call and reshape back -

```
from scipy import stats

out = stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(X.ravel(),mu,sigma).reshape(-1,len(X[0])).T
```